# ¿Cómo pasar y ocupar datos "Int" entre distintas Activities? AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, activity

Estoy haciendo un "Test vocacional" en el cual mi plan era algo así.

El programa te lanza una pregunta como: "¿Prefieres programar o cantar?" (Por ejemplo) y en la parte de las opciones tengo dos `RadioButtons` los cuales tienen como respuesta "Programar" y "Cantar"

Si el usuario presiona el RadioButton "Programar" mi idea es que sume 1 punto al "Area 3" (por ejemplo) y si presiona "Cantar" sume 1 punto al "Area 4"

Y en la parte de abajo (Solo para corroborar que en realidad se guarden los puntos) puse un `TextView`, en el cual muestra el conteo que lleva cada Area.

Todo bien hasta el momento de pasar al `Segundo Activity`, donde quiero hacer lo mismo pero con diferentes preguntas a incisos.

¿Cómo le hago para usar esos mismos datos a otras `Activities` (Por que pretendo hacer bastantes) e irlos sumando a fin de que lleven un conteo? Por ejemplo, que al final del test aparezca un `TextView` y diga, el Área que más se ajusta a tus gustos es "AreaX" y lleve de alguna manera un conteo?

Les adjunto mi código:

- MAIN ACTIVITY:

  public void validar(View view){

  ```
        if(rb1.isChecked()==true){
            int SArea1 = Area1+1;
            String Area1=String.valueOf(SArea1);
            tv_respuesta.setText(Area1);


        } else if (rb2.isChecked()==true){
            int SArea2 = Area2 +1;
            String Area2 = String.valueOf(SArea2);
            tv_respuesta.setText(Area2);
        }

        Intent miIntent=new Intent(this, Pregunta2.class);

        Bundle miBundle=new Bundle();
        miBundle.putInt("SArea1", Area1);
        miBundle.putInt("SArea2", Area2);

        miIntent.putExtra("SArea1", Area1);
        miIntent.putExtra("SArea2", Area2);

        startActivity(miIntent);

    }
  ```
- SIGUIENTE ACTIVITY

  ```
  int valor = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("SArea1");
  int valor2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("SArea2");
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor seria crear una clase con variables estaticas para que la puedas usar en todas las activitys que necesites

Ej:

```
public class Valores {
    public static int Valor1;
    public static int Valor2;
}
```

luego importas la clase en todas las activitis que vallas a usar los valores

Ej:

```
import com.nombreProyecto.Valores;
```

Y en la Actyvity directamente manipulas los valores como desees

Ej:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView Valor1,Valor2;
    Button Siguiente;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Valores.Valor1 = 25;
        Valores.Valor2 = 30;
        Valor1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valor1);
        Valor2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valor2);
        Siguiente = (Button)findViewById(R.id.siguiente);

        Valor1.setText(String.valueOf(Valores.Valor1).toString());
        Valor2.setText(String.valueOf(Valores.Valor2).toString());

        Siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Valores.Valor1 = Valores.Valor1 + 50;
                Intent otro = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                startActivity(otro);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

En la otra Activity vuelves a importar la clase y ya te permite manipular los datos

EJ.

```
import com.sealtosoft.Valores;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView valor1,valor2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        valor1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valor1);
        valor2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valor2);
        valor1.setText(String.valueOf(Valores.Valor1).toString());
        valor2.setText(String.valueOf(Valores.Valor2).toString());

    }
}
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Es una buena idea, lo intentaré.

Pero tengo otra pregunta.
¿Se sigue sumando en las variables o pierden el valor guardado?
La idea es que guarde los valores para que los pueda usar en un futuro. Algo así como un HighScore o Acumulador, no sé.

Comment: Se va seguir sumando la variable mientras la aplicacion este abierta, si se cierra se reinician. Para que perdure se necesita una base de datos

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!